# cannot use res.set() to set header 'x-forwarded-proto'

Tags: node.js, express, bitnami

I am trying to check for http and then redirect to https. However i've gotten stuck and everything i search for and try doesnt seem to work.
I have noticed that on req.secure I'm always going to get false and req.protocol is always going to be 'http' even though i am connected on https in the browser.
I suspect that has something to do with a proxy server as I'm using a node express app on aws lightsail using bitnami linux and req.host comes up as localhost, so i must use 'x-forwarded-host'. I have set app.enable('trust proxy') but it hasn't had any impact.

So, I'm trying to set the following code to redirect from http to https

```
if (req.get("x-forwarded-proto") != "https") {
    res.set("x-forwarded-proto", "https");
    res.redirect("https://" + req.get("x-forwarded-host") + req.originalUrl);
}
```

However this just creates an infite loop as req.get('x-forwarded-proto') returns undefined and res.set('x-forwarded-proto') doesnt actually set a value so the if statement will only return false.
Any idea on what to do and how to move forward?

Edit: I used bitnami bncert to set SSL ecnryption and when configuring i set automatic redirect from http to https and from non-www to www but that doesnt seem to work as i can still access http://example.com without being redirected to https://www.example.com

Comment: Have you tried `req.header("X-Forwarded-Proto")` to get the header

Comment: Yes, it returns undefined. I have looked at req.headers and 'x-forwarded-proto' isn't in the headers